# Keep css floats horizontally aligned

Tags: css, css-float

Why does the div to the right float higher than the two divs to the left? How can i get them all aligned to the top?

HTML

```
 <header>
  <div class="nav" style="width:100%;border:#900 thin solid;">


 <ul id='nav-left' style="list-style-type:none;float:left;width:30%;">
 <li class='nav-link'><a href="/bestsellers">Bookstore</a></li>
 <li class='nav-link'><a href="/authors">Authors</a></li>
 </ul>


 <h1 class='nav-logo' style="width:30%;float:left;background-image:url();">
  <a href="#">Logo</a>
 </h1>


 <div class='nav-right'  style="width:30%;float:right;">
<li class='nav-link'><a href="/bestsellers">Sign in</a></li>
<li class='nav-link'><a href="/authors">Sign up</a></li>
</div>
 <div style="clear:both;">
```

See fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/e6h3jyb4/

Comment: It's because your HTML is invalid. You have list items with no list container. Wrap a `<ul>` around your second list and they line up fine. http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/e6h3jyb4/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have li elements that aren't contained within a ul element. If you wrap those li elements in a ul, then that should fix your alignment issues. In addition, I would suggest that you make all of your columns float: left. Your last column is float: right, and since each has a width of 30%, you will have a large margin between the last two columns. You could also fix that by making your widths 33.33% so it is closer to 1/3 without any leftover margin.

Answer (score 0):

When you add the `<ul>` to the list elements it adds a margin. Add the `<ul>` tag to the right-hand list and it will fix it.